# Using AppleScript, how can I get track details when searching for tracks in my Music library

Tags: bash, applescript

I have a shell script (BASH) which uses the `osascript` command to search the Music app for songs (seems to only work with tracks in my library, not those from Apple Music streaming, but that's for another question).

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Music\" to search playlist \"Music\" for \"${2}\""
```

gives me a comma-delimited string of results of the form

```
shared track id 63569 of user playlist id 60784 of source id 66
```

How can I then query Music using AppleScript through BASH for details for this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this process seemed to work.

```
        search_results=`osascript -e "tell application \"Music\" to search playlist \"Library\" for \"${2}\""`;
        IFS=',' read -r -a results <<< "$search_results"
        for result in "${results[@]}"
        do
            track_id=`echo ${result} | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
            track_details=`osascript -e "tell application \"Music\" to get {name, artist, album} of the track id \"${track_id}\""`;
            echo "${track_details}"
        done
```